# Kendo UI Grid with ODataAction binded to collection

Tags: http, web, asp.net-web-api, odata, kendo-grid

I am trying to use **Kendo UI** Grid with **ODataAction** that is binded to collection. In that case I should specify request type as POST in grid dataSource. But in that case I am loosing sorting, filtering etc functioanlity because OData parameters are passed in th request body and OData Controller is not able to parse it.

```
 URL example: "/odata/MyEntityCollection/MyCustomAction"
```

Currently I am using actions binded to OData service itself to avoid that issue.

```
URL example: "/odata/MyCustomAction"
```

which doesn't require to be POST action. But after some time I got a lot of methods and it become very messy.

Does anyone had similar problem? Is there any better way to avoid ODataAction limitations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be resolved if upgrading WebApi OData to the latest version. Now it is 5.2.0-alpha1-140307.

Please reference this sample:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/WebApi/OData/v4/ODataFunctionSample/

The Top10 method in it addresses your scenario quite well. The only thing you need to do is add [EnableQuery] to it Top10 in ProductsController.cs. Just like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Top10()
{
    var retval = _data.Values.OrderByDescending(p => p.Price).Take(10).ToList();
    return Ok(retval);
}
```

then you can safely add query options to the URL, e.g.,

```
GET http://localhost:9010/odata/Products/Default.Top10()?$orderby=Id desc&$filter=Id gt 46

StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  OData-Version: 4.0
  Date: Mon, 24 Mar 2014 09:54:57 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Content-Length: 304
  Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true;
charset=utf-8
}
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:9010/odata/$metadata#Products","value":[
    {
      "Id":95,"Name":"Product 95","Price":998.542812186546
    },{
      "Id":88,"Name":"Product 88","Price":993.66847052875369
    },{
      "Id":58,"Name":"Product 58","Price":932.89687947039351
    }
  ]
}
```

Note:

1. The namesapce of the new version API has changed from System.Web.Http.OData to System.Web.OData.
2. The version can be found in the packages.config in the sample.

Comment: it seems that it is what I am looking for, but after installing pre-release version of System.Web.OData package I faced with a lot of issues, especially, there is no more Entity method on model builder. It seems that it was replaced by EntityType but it doesn't work correctly and fails on modelBuilder.GetEdmModel() line. The entity '...' does not have a key defined.
Also I found quite usefull article on OData changes: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx

Comment: The mothod Entity is renamed to EntityType in new version. And if a CLR type is added as an Edm Entity Type, it must contains a property Id or {ClassName}Id , which will be added as the Entity Type Key.  The reason is that OData Protocol requires that an Entity Type must have a key or keys. In this case, there must be a  Id or ProductId, and it is case insensitive.

Comment: What if I have entity model with complex key?  Or for example I am using view model which doesn't contain Id at all. We didn't have such restriction on previous version.

Comment: Complex types don't need to have an Id property, so you can modify Top10 method so that it returns a collection of Complex type instances.